# How to set the mobile automation project setup for ios and android with out duplicating the efforts

Tags: selenium, appium, appium-ios, appium-android

When a product has android and ios apps,

Do we have to set up different projects and develop scripts as two individual projects

Or Can we manage in same project?

Trying to understand how to reduce the efforts in developing scripts without much duplication of work.

Answer (score 1):

It depends...

**Native apps:**

If both are native app you will need to develop a solution for each one...

*Development percentage: Android 100% - iOS 100%*

**Web app**

If the app is the same for both because is a web. You will have to do a solution and make a few changes to adapt your code for the other platform that might change... (For example a button xpath is different for both platforms)

*Development percentage: Android 100% - iOS 10% (or vice versa)*

**Hybrid app**

Depends on how many things both apps share... But you wont have to do a 100% development of both platforms...

*Development percentage: Android 100% - iOS -% (Depends...)*

In my case I have developed a solution for a product in both platforms. What I did is create a commons script that will have everything that both sides share... And two small scripts that use that common...

```
--- commons.py
--- Android
------ whatever.py
--- Ios
------ whatever.py
```

Hope it helped

Answer (score 0):

**You can reduce close to 90% of effort on any one platform android/ios by following below simple steps**:

1. Choose a tool that CrossPlatform i.e which works on both iOS and
   Android. Ex: SeeTest, Appium etc
2. Inspect all elements and save in
3. Object repo (xml or any other format) separate from script.
4. Now write an automation script for iOS.
5. Update the Object repo only with Android elements. And your same script of iOS should run on Android.

**Pre-condition/GoodPractices:**

1. Ensure properties of the objects are same. This is standard that has
   to be followed by Android and iOS developers. As much as possible
   the properties of elements should be same across platforms.
2. Ensure flow of the application is same as much as possible, for bothiOS and Android

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Darshan. But If you already have a bunch of tests on a platform and are looking to migrate it onto other, I would suggest a framework like Optimus which is built for this purpose. You can checkout more about it here [Optimus](https://github.com/testvagrant/optimusTemplate)